# Problema con iconos (no se visualizan)

Tags: html, css, web

Buenos días a todos,

Hace poco empecé a programar y la verdad es algo que me gusta, pero sigo siendo un novato y no creo que ni sepa un 1% de todo lo relacionado con HTML y CSS, y es por esto por lo que igual el problema que os voy a presentar es por un fallo absurdo, pero necesito ayuda.

El problema es que al cargar la página web, en vez de salirme el icono me aparece un cuadradito... ¿Sabéis a qué se debe?

Os adjunto por aquí el código de la web...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}


header .title {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}



body .icon-menu {
  color: orange;
  margin: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: era preferible cuando habias agregado el código como texto y no como imagen. Además, ¿De dónde viene el icono?

Comment: El icono es de entypo+, un pack de icomoon

Comment: pero no lo estas importando. Eso debe ser

Comment: ¿Y cómo lo soluciono? No lo entiendo del todo bien lo que quieres decirme

Comment: Hola Unai, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general. En lugar de copiar el código como una imagen, deberías crear un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema y sea más fácil ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: El problema es que no tienes nada dentro de `<span class="icon-menu"></span>`. Escribe algo, lo que fuera, y verás que aparece. Tampoco no veo que tengas un script que añade textContent a tu span.

Answer (score 1):

Como te dicen lo que pasa es que no tienes lo icono en nigun lugar los iconos deben estar en tu proyecto o tomarlos de internet ejemplo:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Asi referncias los iconos de google y entonces ya los puedes usar

```
<i class="material-icons">add_alert</i>
```

En tu caso te falta referenciar los iconos o talvez creas que lo que tienes en el css es un icono ,lo cual no es, intenta con los icnos de google como puse arriba
Aqui encuentras todos los demas :
https://material.io/tools/icons/

Answer (score 0):

El cuadro que aparece es por que el recurso (es decir, el icono), no se carga. Esto puede suceder por diversas razones:

- No se incluye la ruta a la fuente donde se encuentra el icono
- La ruta a la fuente es incorrecta
- La clase es incorrecta
- Problemas de red (si es un recurso externo)

En tu caso parece que no has incluido el paquete de iconos, explico. Los iconos (los que quieres agregar) no son nativos de `html`, por lo tanto de debes obtener ese recurso de algún lado, ya sea descargando el paquete (formados por lo regular de archivos css y svg, woff, eof ,otf, etc.) y colocar la carpeta dentro de tu proyecto u obteniendo la liga a un CDN. Para incluirlos en tu página debes declararlos dentro de la etiqueta `<head>`, al parecer estas agregando tus estilos así que ese concepto ya lo conoces:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>HOLA</title>
</head>
```

Y ahí debes agregar la ruta a tu paquete de fonts, por lo regular solo se adjunta un archivo `.min.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/a/mi/paquete/paquete.min.css" type="text/css">
```

y de esa forma puedes agregarlo. Si aún así no aparece puede ser algún otro problema distinto.